# One specific stub in sinon tests not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I have a problem and can't seem to find the solution.

I'm writing Node.js code and using Sinon to unittest. I am testing a service and stubbing calls to the repository/database. Everything works despite for one repository method where the actual method is invoked instead of its stub. Here's the relevant code.

listingServiceTest.js

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');
var listingService = require('../listingService');
var listingRepository = require('../../repository/listingRepository');
var Listing = require('../../models/interfaceModel/listing');


//some testdata initialization
[..]

describe('saveListing(listing)', function() {
  //everything works fine in here
  [...]
});


describe('saveTags(listingID, tags)', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(listingRepository, 'findTags', function(tags, callback) {
      //This one works fine
        var tags = [{
            text: tags[0],
            tagID: tags[0] + 'ID'
        }];

        setTimeout(function () {
            callback (tags);
        }, 10);
    });

    sinon.stub(listingRepository, 'saveTagCorrelation', function(listingID, tagID, done) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        //Here The actual Method is called instead of the stub ?!?!?
        console.log('im saveTagCorrelation stub');
        done();
      }, 10);
    });

    sinon.stub(listingRepository, 'saveTag', function(tag, callback) {
      //This one works fine
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    listingRepository.findTags.restore();
    listingRepository.saveTag.restore();
    listingRepository.saveTagCorrelation.restore();
  });

  it("saveTags should execute this callback", function() {
    listingService.saveTags(util.slugify(pTitle), pTags, function() {
      //This obviously fails since the the stub isn't called           
      expect(listingRepository.saveTagCorrelation.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal(util.slugify(pTitle));
      expect(listingRepository.saveTagCorrelation.getCall(0).args[1]).to.equal(pTags[0] + 'ID');
      expect(listingRepository.saveTag.getCall(0).args[0]).to.equal(pTags[1]);
      expect(listingRepository.saveTagCorrelation.getCall(1).args[0]).to.equal(util.slugify(pTitle));
      expect(listingRepository.saveTagCorrelation.getCall(1).args[1]).to.equal(pTags[1] + 'ID');
    });
  });
});
```

And here's the repo, that is supposed to be stubbed (I can see in the logs, that the actual method is logging, instead of the stub).

listingRepository.js:

```js
var db = require ('../models/index');
var util = require ('../util');

module.exports = {
    saveListing: [...],

    findTags: [...],

    saveTag: [...],

    saveTagCorrelation: function (listingID, tagID){
        //This is called instead of the stub
        console.log('in actual Method');
        var tagToSave;
        tagToSave = db.tag_listing.build({
            listingID: listingID,
            tagID: tagID
        });
        tagToSave.save();
    },

    getListingByID: [...]
}
```

Am I blind? What am I missing?

Comment: How does this even work if you don't use the async version of jasmine/mocha? Use `function(done)` and call `done` in your cb of the test function.

Comment: I edited in the method body of one of the working functions for comparison. Where exactly do I have to call (and implement) *done*?

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: I see. In the other stubs I called the callback that the service provides, when the stub execution finished. I included the call to done in the saveTagCorrelation stub (see edited code in post), but I still get the same behaviour...